# Qt 5.5: When is duration set from loading a video in media player

Tags: qt, video

I'm wondering when the duration field of mediaplayer is updated by the video you are trying to play.

for instance if i load the video and the click to play it, i can read the duration when i play the video "onPressed"
however if i load the video "onPressed" i can play it, but the duration is set to 0.

When is this field updated or how can i dynamically load load a video and get access to the duration?

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtMultimedia 5.0

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello Video")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

MediaPlayer {
    id: mediaplayer
   // if uncommented, can get duration of video onPressed
   // source: "file:///Users/.../testVideo.mp4"
}

VideoOutput {
    anchors.fill: parent
    source: mediaplayer
}

MouseArea {
    id: playArea
    anchors.fill: parent
    onPressed: {
        // --- If video loaded here, duration is set to 0
        mediaplayer.source= "file:///Users/...../test.mp4"
        console.debug("main::MouseArea::onPressed() - Found media with duration:" + mediaplayer.duration)
        mediaplayer.play();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I assume when the file is actually loaded and the metadata is read, which will happen asynchronously. I'd suggest to just bind to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html#duration-prop or add an `onDurationChanged: { ... }`

Comment: when i put this into a loop, driven by a timer, the onDurationChanged happens once on load time, and then never again.

Comment: Not sure why you need a timer? But well, that’s exactly what i’d expect: the file is loaded, the duration is read and updated, and that’s it. The duration won’t change unless you change the file. Or are you confusing duration (total length of the file, constant) with position or remaining duration? (changing constantly)?

Comment: Do not put anything in loops, timers, etc. This is asynchronous code. The `onDurationChanged` function will be invoked at the right time - when the duration changes. That's the whole point of it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the original OP has already a solution as it's an old question, but I post that in order to help anyone who has the same question.
As far as I know, you can check any metadata property once the media is loaded:

```
Video{
    id: metaData
    source: "your source here...";
    onStatusChanged: {
        if(status === MediaPlayer.Loaded){
            console.log(metaData.duration);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope help someone.